# Add second approved user in php line of code for specific privilage

Tags: php, addition

I have this line of code in the Admin section of a script that gives Admin the privilege to proceed in filling a form.
I want to add a second user to the line for approval but am not stating it correctly, would you mind helping, thanks in advance.
its:

`if(!$controller->isLogged() && $k == 'form') continue;`

Where isLogged means Admin has logged in and can proceed.
I want to add "isUser2" to that line but can't make it work.

I have tried:
`if(!$controller->isAdmin() || ($controller->isUser2() && $k == 'form') continue;`

This allows `isAdmin` to proceed but not isUser2 .. can you help?
thanks

Comment: `if(! ($controller->isAdmin() || ($controller->isUser2()) && $k == 'form')` Note the additional brackets. `&&` binds stronger than `||`...

Comment: the above gave me a blank page - but it did not state a syntax error, I used this and it worked after setting permission for User2:

Comment: if(!$controller->isLogged() && $k == 'form') continue;                       and     if(!$controller->isUser2() && $k == 'form') continue;